# Passing scope variable to directive's controller

Tags: angularjs, directive

My directive has separate controller in js file, which has a scope variable parameterDatabase which need to be populated from calling page. I am unable to find the way to pass value to it.

```
<body ng-app="testAPP" ng-controller="ctl">
Directive Here
<my-cust parameterDATABASE="dt"></my-cust>

<script >
    APP = angular.module("testAPP",['schedule']);

    APP.controller("ctl",function($scope)
                  {
                    $scope.dt = {date:"02-03-2017",sDay:"Thu",sTime:"01:00"};
    }) // end of controller

    APP.directive("myCust",function()
    {
        return{
                scope:{
                    parameterDATABASE:'='
                },
                controller:"scheduleCtrl",
                templateUrl:"templateForDirective.html"
              }
    })
</script>
```

The scheduleCtrl has a variable parameterDATABASE too.

part of Directive's contrller

```
var APP = angular.module('schedule',[]);
 APP.controller('scheduleCtrl',function($scope,$filter) 
{ $scope.parameterDATABASE=[]; // This is the variable I want to populate
```

..............

Comment: A little confused on your question.  If I am understanding your code, it seems like your custom controller (in another file, apparently not pictured above) should be available inside that controller as `$scope.parameterDATABASE`.  Is that what you are looking for?  It would be helpful if you posted that code as well, and maybe clarified what is expected and what is actually occurring.

Comment: var APP = angular.module('schedule',[]);
APP.controller('scheduleCtrl',function($scope,$filter)
{

    $scope.parameterDATABASE=[]; // This is the variable I want to populate

Comment: They need to be part of the same angular module for a start. You're using 3 modules: `ng-app="testAPP"` at the top, `"MyRTO"` with one controller and `"schedule"` with the directive's controller. That's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** According to some angular naming conventions, the attribute name of a directive should be converted into **`camelCase`**.

So, **`parameterDATABASE`** in the `html Directive` should be **`parameter-database`**

So, inside the directive, you should use that as,

```
scope: {
       parameterDatabase: '='
}
```

**So, `parameterDatabase` maps to ==> `parameter-database`**

**2)** you can also use, `parameterdatabase` directly in both places without capitalizing.

Eg:  `parameter-database="dt"` in `html directive`

```
  scope: {
           parameterdatabase: '='
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctl">

<isolate-scope-with-controller parameter-database="dt" add="addCustomer()"></isolate-scope-with-controller>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

 app.controller("ctl",function($scope)
                  {
                    $scope.dt = {date:"02-03-2017",sDay:"Thu",sTime:"01:00"};
    }) // end of
    
  app.directive('isolateScopeWithController', function () {
      
    var controller = ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  console.log($scope.parameterDatabase)

      }],
        
      template = '<h1>I am from directive controller</h1><br><h2>{{parameterDatabase}}</h2>';
      
      return {
          restrict: 'EA', //Default in 1.3+
          scope: {
              parameterDatabase: '='
          },
          controller: controller,
          template: template
      };
  });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**PLEASE RUN THE ABOVE SNIPPET**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/yACK7Ff1MEyngTpcBGJY?p=preview)

Comment: @user3513192, pls check my answer.